# 1e100.net Remote Address downloading something to my system behind the scenes

Tags: windows-8

I have a brand new PC I got yesterday and am forced to use a dialup connection in the area I live in. Something was downloading from my internet last night behind the scenes even after I had all automatic updates turned off. According to the TCPView program from Microsoft's website, programs  (mostly Firefox and Yahoo Messenger) are showing 1e100.net in the Remote Address. It happens at launch for Firefox each time and after that it happens at random while the programs are opened.

WhoIs info says it's owned by someplace called "MarkMonitor" and Google is also mentioned in the information. Last night whatever it was downloading, it was downloading for over 4 hours straight and tying up the internet. In TCPView I can now close the connection when I see it doing it, but how can I disable/remove it completely in the future? I don't know my way around Windows 8.1 very well but I am not finding any references anywhere.

I found this site through Bing doing a search for the "MarkMonitor" company and hoped somebody here might have an idea. I'm new to Windows 8 and am not very skilled with networking and such. Any info would be appreciated to free up my dialup connection so I can do what I want to do again though. Thank you!

Comment: 1e100 = 1 googol. 1e100.net is Google's domain.

Comment: There is one (and only one) very simple way to prevent your computer from accessing any Google services at all. You simply disable all internet connections on the computer, then it won't communicate with Google anymore.

Comment: If you read the whois data, it clearly states that it is google: http://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx?action=whois%3a1e100.net&run=networktools